# PHP, XML -> Create XML from Node Set + Data

Tags: php, xml

Am wondering if someone can help in the best method to accomplish this.

We have a XML with various data sets, Within the XML is a Set of Data per Channel.

Each Channel runs its own program.

What i was hoping to do, is if ChannelA was to process the XML 
And it had a error for one reason or another, Can i simply extract that NODE set it was processing and build a XML from it.

or do i have to declare each NODE set to build the XML then essentially import it?

The XML has around 30/40 Nodes (Am posting like this as an example) so typing these out in PHP is just going to be ugly, and down the line as we add more sets, its just going to be horrible to maintain it.

```
<data>
<MainUpdate>
<Chan>5</Chan>
<Data1></<Data1>
<Data2></<Data2>
<Data3></<Data3>
<Data4></<Data4>
<Data5></<Data5>
</MainUpdate>
<MainUpdate>
<Chan>8</Chan>
<Data1></<Data1>
<Data2></<Data2>
<Data3></<Data3>
<Data4></<Data4>
<Data5></<Data5>
</MainUpdate>
<MainUpdate>
<Chan>10</Chan>
<Data1></<Data1>
<Data2></<Data2>
<Data3></<Data3>
<Data4></<Data4>
<Data5></<Data5>
</MainUpdate>
</data>
```

If Channel8 processes this XML, and its only processing Channel8 Data
I want to be able to create a XML with just:

```
<data>
<MainUpdate>
<Chan>8</Chan>
<Data1></<Data1>
<Data2></<Data2>
<Data3></<Data3>
<Data4></<Data4>
<Data5></<Data5>
</MainUpdate>
</data>
```

Without delcaring all the nodes

Comment: sorry, I don't get it what you want. Copy `<MainUpdate>` with a specific `<Chan>' to a new XML file?

Comment: Yes, If Channel Processes:
From <MainUpdate>->Chan8-</MainUpdate>
I want to build the XML From 
<MainUpdate>
<Chan>8</Chan>
<Data1></<Data1>
<Data2></<Data2>
<Data3></<Data3>
<Data4></<Data4>
<Data5></<Data5>
</MainUpdate>

I can do this, But the way i am doing this is using DOM and creating the NODES for each Value and its a really poor way of doing it. 
Am sure there has to be a better method. 
i..e PHP has loaded in the XML, it holds the values, Why can i not fund a function to write out what it has read in, without declaring and writing all the nodes. 
Is that abit more clear? Sorry

Answer (score 0):

- use `xpath` to select the desired node (and its children) and
- `importNode()` to get it to a new `DOMDocument`

code example:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc); // assume original XML in $doc
$e = $xpath->query("/data/MainUpdate[Chan = '8']")->item(0);
```

Note the condition in `[]`, assuming `<Chan>` as unique, the resulting `DOMNodeList` will have 1 `DOMElement`, of which we grab the first and only and store it in `$e`. 
`$e` is `NULL` if there is no such `<Chan>`, check this before proceeding.

Now create a new document with `<data></data>` as root and import `$e`:

```
$newdoc = new DOMDocument();
$newdoc->loadXML("<data />");

$e = $newdoc->importNode($e, true);
$newdoc->documentElement->appendChild($e);
```

see it working: https://eval.in/513276